# TestNG with Selenium Data and Keyword Driven Framework

Tags: selenium, testng

I am new to TestNG. I'm using Hybrid Framework For Automation Testing, it's Hybrid Architecture based, in which Keyword(Java Methood name) and data is provided in Excel sheet, and based on that information each test case gets executed.

But I am not able to run the same test suite in multiple browsers at a time, so do you have any idea how I can integrate TestNG and do this.

What I want is if there is any way where I can specify:

- run this many TC on Browser1 with user Role1,
- and run 2nd suite on Browser2 With user Role2.

My .xml File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <suite name="Suite" parallel="methods"> 
    <test name="Test"> 
      <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter> 
      <parameter name="browserName1" value="chrome"></parameter> 
      <classes> 
        <class name="com.commonFunctions.ThreadLocalDemo" /> 
      </classes> 
    </test> <!-- Test --> 
  </suite>
```

My TestNG class is:

```
public class ThreadLocalDemo { 
  @org.testng.annotations.Parameters({"browserName"}) 
  @Test public void testMethod1(String browserName) 
    throws { DriverScript.Main(); } 
  @Test(dataProvider="browsername1") public void testMethod2(String browserName1) 
    throws { DriverScript.Main(); } 
}
```

The script code is at the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8YGjjoQPzG_NUY3Nk81SU5fNGs/view

Comment: Kindly share your web driver code and xml of test NG.

Comment: My .xml File is as                                                                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">

    <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <parameter name="browserName1" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.commonFunctions.ThreadLocalDemo" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite>

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8YGjjoQPzG_NUY3Nk81SU5fNGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Shared @HelpingHands

Comment: it should be like parallel = "tests" - Did you try this?

Comment: yes Tried this...my TestNG class is as:                                             public class ThreadLocalDemo {
 @org.testng.annotations.Parameters({"browserName"})
  @Test
     public void testMethod1(String browserName) throws  {
  
  DriverScript.Main();
     }
  
     @Test(dataProvider="browsername1")
     public void testMethod2(String browserName1) throws  {
      DriverScript.Main();
     }
}

Comment: But only Firefox Browser is being open

Comment: Can you please share all you code properly with question. Please update your question and put all code there properly..

Comment: I've edited the question to add the code snippets and link from the comments.